# WebPack execute function before build starts

Tags: javascript, build, synchronization, webpack, build-process

I need to execute one JavaScript function before the Webpack starts its building process. The function just takes `.scss` files and concatenate them into one.

After that Webpack should take the result file. Is there an option to do that?

At the moment I run the function before the `module.exports` in `webpack.config.js`, but it seems that its not synchronous operation. Module.exports execute before the `concat()` function ends and Webpack can't find .scss file.

```
function concat(opts) {
  (...)
}

concat({ src : styles,  dest : './css/style.scss' });

module.exports = [
   (...)
]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems a little bit odd to concat scss files before running Webpack as those kind of operations are usually handled by Webpack itself.

That being said, there's a few way of solving this.

The most obvious way would be to extract the `concat` parts to a separate file (e.g. `prepare.js`) and then run start the build process by running something along this line: `node prepare.js && webpack`. That'll first run prepare and if that exits without error webpack will be run. Usually that'll be added to the `scripts` part of your package.json, e.g.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "node prepare.js && webpack"
}
```

To achieve the same but in a more Webpack integrated way you could do the same thing where you extract the `concat` part to a separate file and then let Webpack execute that file, before build starts, with the help of [Webpack Shell Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin), e.g.

```
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new WebpackShellPlugin({
      onBuildStart:['node prepare.js']
    })
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. Are you sure that Webpack can take care about operations like those? I didn't find any solution for my "concat" problem, thats why I'm using external function. Maybe some tutorial for that?

Comment: All depends on how you go about to build your stylesheets. In a Webpack world the styles are usually `require`d  in your javascript source files and Webpack then picks them up, runs it through scss compilers/postcss/whatnot and then either outputs the finished product as inline style or a (or multiple) `.css` file. Take a look at https://www.bensmithett.com/smarter-css-builds-with-webpack/ , http://survivejs.com/webpack/building-with-webpack/separating-css/ and https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html

Comment: Just a heads up that webpack-shell-plugin does not play along with the `--watch` flag for webpack: https://github.com/1337programming/webpack-shell-plugin/issues/60

Answer (score 12):

You can add any code at any phase of the building, using the [Compiler Hooks](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/).

The [compile](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#compile) hook is called before (and every time) the compilation begins, so you probably want to use that:

```js
config = {
    //...
    plugins: [
        {
            apply: (compiler) => {
                compiler.hooks.compile.tap("MyPlugin_compile", () => {
                    console.log("This code is executed before the compilation begins.");
                });
            },
        },
    ],
    //...
};
```